# Update incorrect foreign keys?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have some corrupt data that needs to be cleaned.  How can I accomplish this, given the current state of the data?

The Share table holds a foreign key referencing the Room table.  Currently there are duplicates in the Room table.  It should be the case that many Shares point to one Room.  However, the situation is that there is an entry in the Room table for each Share.  The Room entries are identical and I wish to remove the redundant entries.  Obviously, the first thing to do is correct the references in the Share table.

Redundant Room entries:
[image: Rooms]
Corresponding Share entries:
[image]

How do I make all the Share.room_id's point to the same entry from the Room table?  I have attempted various Update statements without success. The following Update statement does not make sense because I am specifying the Room entry, which of course does not work.  But I must close the join on the Room table somehow.

```
UPDATE share s
   SET room_id = (SELECT DISTINCT MIN(s.room_id) FROM room r
                   WHERE s.room_id = r.id
                   GROUP BY ROLLUP(r.addition_id, r.area, r.first_effective_at))
```

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Just wanted to post the Update statement that worked for me:

```
UPDATE share s
  SET room_id = (SELECT MIN(r.id) FROM room r
              JOIN room r2
                ON (r.addition_id = r2.addition_id 
                  AND r.area = r2.area 
                  AND r.first_effective_at =  r2.first_effective_at
                  AND r.permanent_id = r2.permanent_id)
                  WHERE r2.id = s.room_id
              GROUP BY r.addition_id, r.area, r.first_effective_at, r.permanent_id);
```

It was super slow and is probably terribly inefficient, but it only needs to run once.

Comment: So what is the unique key in ROOMS? Apparently it isn't ID - that's obviously just a (useless) synthetic primary key.  So how can we tell which rows in ROOMS are duff and which are kosher?

Comment: Hum.  My apologies, I don't think my response will answer your question.  The foreign key Addition_Id in Room points to an entry in the Building_Addition table.  The Building_Addition table has a reference to the Building table.  But, I don't really care which of the matching Room entries is used.

Comment: I did omit columns from the example data I posted.  The Room table does have a permanent_id column.

Comment: Now you need to zap all the surplus ROOMS records.  Then enforce a *meaningful* primary key.  Otherwise this won't be something which "needs to run once".

Comment: I did zap the surplus Rooms. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps something like this, untested:

```
update share s
   set room_id =
         (select min(r.id)
            from   room r
                 join
                   (select addition_id, area, first_effective_at
                      from room
                     where s.room_id = id)
                   as r2
             on r.addition_id = r2.addition_id and r.area = r2.area and r.first_effective_at =  r2.first_effective_at
          group by r.addition_id, r.area, r.first_effective_at);
```

Comment: Thank you.  I was able to make it work with a variation on this query.